# Anchor click even not firing after PJAX page load

Tags: javascript, web, pjax

I am having a pretty strange problem with a website I am messing around with, and I can't wrap my head around what may be going wrong. I am using PJAX on the site, and the have a div in my body with the id of `#page-contents`.

The code I am using to setup PJAX is as follows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(document).pjax('a', '#page-contents', {
            fragment: '#page-contents',
            timeout: 2000
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know that the setup is correct because I edited the PJAX file to fire an alert whenever it swapped out the content of my `#page-contents` div, and I do see that alert when I would expect to (i.e., on link clicks).

I have a navbar along the top (a bootstrap navbar) and I was initially having trouble keeping track of which navbar item would be marked as active. I have solved this problem using the following javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");

        var nextPage = $(this).attr("href");
        nextPage = nextPage.substring(nextPage.indexOf(window.location.hostname) + window.location.hostname.length);
        switch(true) {
            case nextPage == "/about":
                $("#about-nav").addClass("active");
                break;
            case nextPage == "/contact":
                $("#contact-nav").addClass("active");
                break;
            case nextPage == "/resume":
                $("#resume-nav").addClass("active");
                break;
            case nextPage.indexOf("/projects") != -1:
                $("#projects-nav").addClass("active");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works fine for all links I have in my navbar, but I have found that any links I have inside my `#page-contents` div will not trigger my above script. I know that PJAX is still working as the page changes and the alert I inserted displays.

A few things I have found in my own testing:

- I have also found that if I directly load an address that contains a non-navbar link and then click that link, it will work. But coming back to that page via a pjax reload and then clicking the link will not fire my event.
- Adding a test class to one of my anchors and then associating some event with that class has the same problems.

Does anybody know why my script would not be getting executing? Or maybe I am just missing something obvious.

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: The website in question is my personal site I am working on, the link is http://rosshays.me, the page I first noticed this on was my [about page](http://rosshays.me/about). (The site is a work in progress as you'll clearly see.) As mentioned about, going to the about page directly and clicking the link will work, but if you navigate to the about page and then try to click the link in the page, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ross-

I had a similar issue and I know how to solve this; this script is not binding to the new elements because it is not being re-ran on the new elements once they are loaded.

Please put your function in an external .js file. Once complete, you can add this script to your header:

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});
            $.getScript("YOUR SCRIPT FILE PATH HERE', true);?>");                           
            });
```

You will have to add more `$.getScript` calls for any other javascript/jQuery that is needed in order to enable the events you want to take place. (Example: you may need to reload jQuery)

This will re-apply the jquery and javascript to the new elements that are loaded via PJAX.

*One thing to note: If you are using twitter bootstrap, do not re-call the bootstrap script with `$.getScript` as it will cancel itself out on every other re-load.